# Access Tables from HIve using Hcatalog REST

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hcatalog

I installed Hcatalog with CDH4 (on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit) and I am currently trying to [Access Table Information with REST](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_19_8.html)

I restarted the webhcat-server `service webhcat-server restart`.
Then I executed this at the terminal,

```
curl http://localhost:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database/?user.name=hive
```

and I got,

`{"databases":["default","testas"]}`

as expected (and correct).

I tried this several times and got the same output.

Then I tried the same in my browser and I got,

```
{"statement":"show databases like '*';","error":"unable to show databases for: *","exec":
{"stdout":"","stderr":"Hive history file=/tmp/hive/hive_job_log_9f5d4411-e8f4-4c7e-a8db-
3bc53a565db8_2034639464.txt\nSLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.\nSLF4J: 
Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-
1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]\nSLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-
1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]\nSLF4J: See 
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.\n","exitcode":143}}
```

Then I came back to the terminal and tried,

```
curl http://localhost:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database/?user.name=hive
```

which doesnt work now, and outputs

```
{"statement":"show databases like '*';","error":"unable to show databases for: *","exec":
{"stdout":"","stderr":"Hive history file=/tmp/hive/hive_job_log_ce3f8d69-35b1-4617-b3a5-
624be0a500cc_268094038.txt\nSLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.\nSLF4J: 
Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-
1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]\nSLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-
1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]\nSLF4J: See 
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.\nOK\nFAILED: Hive 
Internal Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException(Shutdown in progress, cannot add a 
shutdownHook)\njava.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress, cannot add a 
shutdownHook\n\tat 
org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:152)\n\t
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2352)\n\tat 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2324)\n\tat 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:351)\n\tat 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:194)\n\tat 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.clear(Context.java:381)\n\tat 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.close(Driver.java:1553)\n\tat 
org.apache.hcatalog.cli.HCatCli.processCmd(HCatCli.java:276)\n\tat 
org.apache.hcatalog.cli.HCatCli.processLine(HCatCli.java:205)\n\tat 
org.apache.hcatalog.cli.HCatCli.main(HCatCli.java:164)\n\tat 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)\n\tat 
sun.reflect.D","exitcode":143}}
```

Why is this happening?

**Note:**

In the `/etc/hcatalog/proto-hive-site.xml`, I changed `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword` from pre existing `PASSWORD` to the password to `hive`.

I know there is a `log4j` error, but I doubt that has anything to do with this

Comment: Hi VusP, I am facing the same issue, did you get any solution in this ?

Comment: @MukeshS Nothing currently. I didn't try it again after that. Will post it here when I do try it again.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are having many slf4j jars with different versions in your class path. This is a common error thrown while running java programs. Please check the hive logs (hive history files) for more information.             Please try to remove the unnecessary version of jars.